# regular expression in excel for numbers before a slash

Tags: regex, excel, openoffice-calc

In the example below, I need to change everything before the final slash to jreviews/

so in the example below the first line would become

jreviews/159256_0907131531001639107_std.jpg

i am using open office find and replace tool, I see there is an option for regex but i dont know how to do this. How can I find and replace the img.agoda urls and everything thats a number and slash, and replace that with jreviews/ ?

but keeping the numbers after that final slash, because these are the filename.

```
    http://img.agoda.net/hotelimages/159/159256/159256_0907131531001639107_std.jpg
    http://img.agoda.net/hotelimages/161/161941/161941_1001051215002307125_std.jpg
    http://img.agoda.net/hotelimages/288/288595/288595_111017161615_std.jpg
    http://img.agoda.net/hotelimages/289/289890/289890_13081511070014319856_std.jpg
    http://img.agoda.net/hotelimages/305/305075/305075_120427175058_std.jpg
    http://img.agoda.net/hotelimages/305/305078/305078_120427175537_std.jpg
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

Replace the below match with "CustomName/"

```
^.+[/$]
```

Answer (score 2):

Regex seems like overkill, at least for your examples. Since they all have the same number of subfolders, a simple Find and Replace with wildcards works for me. Here's how I did it in Excel:

[image]

Just replace `http://*/*/*/*/` with `jreviews/`.